# How to get the value of a toggle switch in a datatable , laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to update the status column , by using the following code :

My Controller :

```
   function getdata(Request $request)
{
    if(request()->ajax())
    {
        return datatables()->of(Casting::latest()->get())
            ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                $button = '<table><tr><td>';
                $button .= '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Modifier</button>';
                $button .= '</td><td>';
                $button .= ' <label  class="switch" >';
                $button .= '  <input type="checkbox" id="'.$data->id.'" class="switch" ';
                
                if ($data->status == 1) {

                    $button .= "checked";
                }

                $button .= '><span class="slider round"></span></label>';
                $button .= '</td></tr></table>';

                return $button;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->make(true);
    }
    return view('Casting.castingss');
}



 public function changeStatus(Request $request)


    {
        $casting = Casting::find($request->id);
        $casting->status = $request->status;
        $casting->save();
  
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Status change successfully.']);
    }
```

My script :

```
$('#datatableRows').DataTable({

  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax:{
   url: "{{ route('castingss.getdata') }}",
  },
  columns:[
  
   {
    data: 'casting_photo',
    name: 'casting_photo',
    render: function(data, type, full, meta){
              return "<img src={{ URL::to('/') }}/castingimages/" + data +  " class='list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left' />";
    },
    orderable: false
   },
   {data:'casting_name',
    name: 'casting_name',
    render:function(data,type,full,meta){
      return "<a href='profile'>" + data + "</a>";
    }
   },
    {
    data: 'casting_cin',
    name: 'casting_cin'
   },
    {
    data: 'casting_phone',
    name: 'casting_phone'

            },
   
   {
    data: 'action',
    name: 'action',
    orderable: false
   }
  ],
     
 });

$(document).on('change', '.switch', function(){

        var status = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0; 

          var id = $(this).attr('id');

            $.ajax({

            type: "GET",

            dataType: "json",

            url: '/changeStatus',

            data: {'status': status, 'id': id},

            success: function(data){

              console.log(data.success)

            }

        });

    });
```

When I ewecute , I get the following error : "message": "Creating default object from empty value" In my Controller , line :  `$casting->status = $request->status;`

I guess there is no value for status variable.
how can I guet the value of the switch custom inside the datatable
How can I resolve this issue ? if you have any idea help me

Comment: may be issue with id is undefined .try alert(id) whether you get value or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two possibilities .One is data is  received empty so better check once data passed to controller is proper.
If its proper then passed id to Casting model is not there.So add validation for that

```
 public function changeStatus(Request $request)
{
   $request->validate(['status'=>'required','id'=>'required']);
    $casting = Casting::find($request->id);
    if($casting){
    $casting->status = $request->status;
    $casting->save();
   return response()->json(['success'=>'Status change successfully.']);
    }
   return response()->json(['failed'=>'Status change failed.'],422);
       
    }
```

**Updated**

Since you have used `switch` class name to `label` as well as for `input checkbox` so

```
 $button .= '  <input type="checkbox" id="'.$data->id.'" class="switch selectRow" ';
```

then change

```
$(document).on('change', '.selectRow', function(){
```

Comment: also better first alert in javacript id is getting or not

Comment: , it gets the id , but I get now {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"id":["The id field is required."]}}

Comment: then id value not passing.the issue with id is undefined mostly.check alert(id) before ajax call

Comment: look like you have used switch class to label as well as for input so add one more new class to input which is unique to input and then change $(document).on('change', '.switch', function(){ here

Comment: I have a question if it is possible, can I at the same time change the status to 0 and hide it from the datatable?

Comment: yes you can .set id to row with class for example <tr class=" individualrow-id" then on success based on $('.ndividualrow-id'+id).hide();

Comment: please can you give me an exampe

Comment: @HaJar.could you please open new question so some can provide you sollution